# CTE Needing ; Or Not

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, cte

I have discovered that when I run a `CTE` in a query window it must have the leading `;` but if I am going to run a `CTE` in a stored procedure it does not need the `;`

To me, it would be needed in both places or neither place.  Why is this punctuation need in one area and not the other?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that a CTE needs a leading `;`, but that the statement before must end with a `;`.

If the statement with the CTE is the first statement in a batch (or the first statement in your SP), then there's no statement before it to end with a `;`

There's a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server) about it with more detail.